# How to use Pact Broker badges

Tags: pact, pact-broker

It seems I'm missing something vital but I cannot see that the badges are available for my pacts at the URI's given in the examples here: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Provider-verification-badges

Namely: https://your-broker/pacts/provider/PROVIDER/consumer/CONSUMER/latest/badge.svg
(PROVIDER/CONSUMER are replaced with existing values)

I simply get a 404 response when trying to access.

I'm using pact-jvm v3.5.7 and pactbroker v2.6.0.

What I'm I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I think 2.6.0 had the badges turned off by default for privacy reasons. I've recently enabled them by default as I think the benefits outweigh the negatives. Upgrade to the latest version of the broker, or set `enable_badge_resources = true` in the Pact Broker configuration (config.ru).

While you're at it, check out the badges config section in the wiki. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Configuration#badges

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property `enable_badge_resources = true` as suggested did the trick. Thanks!